# Complicated multiple bar and ribbon/area chart of boarding/alighting bus passenger in ggplo2 [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to produce a bar chart combining ribbon/area chart which illustrates boarding/alighting passengers of BRT/MRT lines at each station as well as sectional passenger volume along a corridor by direction.

Initial data frame is shown below:

```
df <- data.frame(
mode=c("mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt","mrt",
       "brt","brt","brt","brt","brt","brt","brt","brt","brt","brt"),
direction=c("Northbound","Northbound","Northbound","Northbound","Northbound",
            "Southbound","Southbound","Southbound","Southbound","Southbound",
            "Northbound","Northbound","Northbound","Northbound","Northbound",
            "Southbound","Southbound","Southbound","Southbound","Southbound"),
station=c("a","b","c","d","e","e","d","c","b","a","a","b","c","d","e","e","d","c","b","a"),
on=c(40,30,20,10,0,40,30,20,10,0,20,15,10,5,0,20,15,10,5,0),
off=c(0,10,20,30,40,0,10,20,30,40,0,5,10,15,20,0,5,10,15,20),
volume=c(40,60,60,40,0,40,60,60,40,0,20,30,30,20,0,20,30,30,20,0))
```

Initial data frame is converted into long format for `ggplot2`.

```
library(tidyverse)
    df2 <- df %>% gather(key=key,value=trip,on,off) %>% mutate(
                station=factor(station,levels=c("a","b","c","d","e"),labels=c("a","b","c","d","e")),
                key=factor(key,levels=c("on","off"),labels=c("on","off")),
                direction=factor(direction,levels=c("Northbound","Southbound"),
                                           labels=c("Northbound","Southbound")),
                mode=factor(mode,levels=c("mrt","brt"),labels=c("mrt","brt")))
```

Printed `df2` look like this:

```
> df2
   mode  direction station volume key trip
1   mrt Northbound       a     40  on   40
2   mrt Northbound       b     60  on   30
3   mrt Northbound       c     60  on   20
4   mrt Northbound       d     40  on   10
5   mrt Northbound       e      0  on    0
6   mrt Southbound       e     40  on   40
7   mrt Southbound       d     60  on   30
8   mrt Southbound       c     60  on   20
9   mrt Southbound       b     40  on   10
10  mrt Southbound       a      0  on    0
11  brt Northbound       a     20  on   20
12  brt Northbound       b     30  on   15
13  brt Northbound       c     30  on   10
14  brt Northbound       d     20  on    5
15  brt Northbound       e      0  on    0
16  brt Southbound       e     20  on   20
17  brt Southbound       d     30  on   15
18  brt Southbound       c     30  on   10
19  brt Southbound       b     20  on    5
20  brt Southbound       a      0  on    0
21  mrt Northbound       a     40 off    0
22  mrt Northbound       b     60 off   10
23  mrt Northbound       c     60 off   20
24  mrt Northbound       d     40 off   30
25  mrt Northbound       e      0 off   40
26  mrt Southbound       e     40 off    0
27  mrt Southbound       d     60 off   10
28  mrt Southbound       c     60 off   20
29  mrt Southbound       b     40 off   30
30  mrt Southbound       a      0 off   40
31  brt Northbound       a     20 off    0
32  brt Northbound       b     30 off    5
33  brt Northbound       c     30 off   10
34  brt Northbound       d     20 off   15
35  brt Northbound       e      0 off   20
36  brt Southbound       e     20 off    0
37  brt Southbound       d     30 off    5
38  brt Southbound       c     30 off   10
39  brt Southbound       b     20 off   15
40  brt Southbound       a      0 off   20
```

There are two types of output that I am trying to reach:

**Type 1: Separate board/alight barplot by mode**
[image]

**Type 2: Stacked board/alight barplot by mode**
[image]

Currently I could make following figure by following scripts:

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=station)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=trip,fill=interaction(mode,key)),stat="identity",
         position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),width=0.8) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=volume,group=interaction(mode,key),fill=mode),alpha=0.2) +
facet_wrap(~direction,nrow=2)
```

[image]

The issues are:

**Type 1:**  
 - Cannot make white space between `mrt` and `brt` in x-axis with label of `mode`. I would make it to clarify the difference of each mode.  
 - <strike>`interaction` function in x-axis does not provide ideal order of `mode` and `key`. As mentioned in the first point, `mrt-on`,`mrt-off`,`brt-on`,`brt-off` is the best positioning of labels.</strike>  *It could be solved*

**Type 2:**  
 - Cannot make grouped and stacked barplot.

**Common issues**  
 - <strike>Ribbon is not stepwise shape</strike> *It could be solved*  
 - <strike>Ribbon is not stacked (and `position="stack"` returns an error)</strike> *It could be solved*  
 - <strike>Ribbon make bars less-visible (perhaps could be adjusted by `alpha` but it is much better if anteroposterior relation can be set)</strike> *It could be solved*

I am not sure if such adjustment could be made in `ggplot2` but I would have your suggestions to obtain ideal graph.  
I also tested some other examples, such as `geom_step` but did not work well. Another issue is that if I use `geom_area` instead of `geom_ribbon`, unnecessary value stored in `volume` field related to `key==off` is also plotted:

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=station)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=trip,fill=interaction(mode,key)),stat="identity",
         position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),width=0.8) +
geom_area(aes(y=volume,group=interaction(mode,key),fill=interaction(mode,key)),position="stack") +
facet_wrap(~direction,nrow=2)
```

**Example of `geom_area`**
[image]

I highly appreciate your suggestion to obtain ideal outcome that I am trying to produce for these few days.

== UPDATED ==
I could have slight update of the figure as shown below:
[image]

I used `geom_stepribbon`, an extension of ggplot2:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcmdrPlugin.KMggplot2/vignettes/geom-stepribbon.html

Also, it is necessary to adjust passenger volume for southbound using `lag` as mentioned below:

[Generate a Filled geom_step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887088/generate-a-filled-geom-step/41962072#41962072)

```
## Prepare df for geom_stepribbon [it requires some more packages]
df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(direction) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(volume),funs(ifelse(direction=="Southbound",lag(volume),.))) %>% data.frame()

## Plot
ggplot(df3,aes(x=station)) +
geom_stepribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=volume,group=mode,fill=mode),alpha=0.5) +
geom_bar(aes(y=trip,fill=interaction(mode,key)),stat="identity",
         position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),width=0.8) +
facet_wrap(~direction,nrow=2)
```

However, I still have following issues:

- <strike>Order of bars*It could be solved*</strike>
- Space between `mode` in type1
- Stacked and grouped bars in type2

Further suggestions are appreciated.

== UPDATED ver.2==  
Remaining issue on *order of bar* is solved by manually changing levels of factor in the following script.

```
ggplot(df5,aes(x=station)) +
geom_stepribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=volume,group=mode,fill=mode),alpha=0.5) +
geom_bar(aes(y=trip,fill=factor(interaction(mode,key),
                    levels=c("mrt.on","mrt.off","brt.on","brt.off"),
                    labels=c("MRT-Board","MRT-Alight","BRT-Board","BRT-Alight"))),
                    stat="identity", position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),width=0.8) +
facet_wrap(~direction,nrow=2)
```

[image]

Perhaps space between bars of `MRT` and `BRT` is a bit complicated.
Suggestions for one remaining issue, *stacked and grouped bars* are still welcomed.  
***It is reported that stacking and grouping are not possible to be done at the same time by @Axeman***

== FINAL UPDATE ==
As I could reach the one that I need to produce, I will share the scripts herewith:
However, I am still confusing how `scale_fill_manual` works. Order of `values` and `breaks/labels` are not corresponded each other. I just manually adjusted it based on the result and highly appreciate if you could provide any suggestions to make the codes better.

[image]

```
    ## Set year
        year <- 18

    ## df5 corresponds to df3 in the previous update
        ## Maximum passenger
        max.mrt.n <- df5 %>% filter(mode=="mrt" & direction=="Northbound") %>%
                             summarize(max=max(volume)) %>% as.integer()
        max.mrt.s <- df5 %>% filter(mode=="mrt" & direction=="Southbound") %>%
                             summarize(max=max(volume)) %>% as.integer()
        max.brt.n <- df5 %>% filter(mode=="brt" & direction=="Northbound") %>%
                             summarize(max=max(volume)) %>% as.integer()
        max.brt.s <- df5 %>% filter(mode=="brt" & direction=="Southbound") %>%
                             summarize(max=max(volume)) %>% as.integer()
        max.mrt <- data.frame(direction=c("Northbound","Southbound"),label=c(max.mrt.n,max.mrt.s))
        max.brt <- data.frame(direction=c("Northbound","Southbound"),label=c(max.brt.n,max.brt.s))

        ## Set print window
        png("CorridorPax.png",height=720, width=960, res=144)
        ## Specify data frame and x-axis
        g <- ggplot(df5,aes(x=station)) +
        ## Draw step ribbon chart
        geom_stepribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=volume,
                        group=factor(mode,levels=c("mrt","brt"),labels=c("MRT Pax.","BRT Pax.")),
                        fill=factor(mode,levels=c("mrt","brt"),labels=c("MRT Pax.","BRT Pax."))),
                        alpha=0.4) +
        ## Draw bar chart
        geom_bar(aes(y=trip,fill=factor(interaction(mode,key),
                            levels=c("mrt.on","mrt.off","brt.on","brt.off"),
                            labels=c("MRT-Board","MRT-Alight","BRT-Board","BRT-Alight"))),
                            stat="identity", position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),width=0.8) +
        ## Facet by direction
        facet_wrap(~direction,nrow=2) +
        ## Appearance
            ## Title and xy-axis
            ggtitle(paste0("Passenger volume of MRT and BRT along the corridor in 20",year)) +
            xlab("Station") +
            ylab("Number of Daily Passengers ('000)") +
            ## Theme
            theme_bw() +
            ## Rotate label and adjust font size
            theme(title=element_text(size=10),
                  axis.title=element_text(size=10),
                  axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.25,size=10),
                  axis.text.y=element_text(size=8),
                  legend.text=element_text(size=8)
                  ) +
            ## Limit and breaks of y-axis
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,by=5),limits=c(0,60)) +
            ## Legend
            scale_fill_manual(name="Passenger",
                              values=c("cadetblue2","darkorange","gold",
                                       "royalblue","firebrick","lawngreen"),
                              breaks=c("MRT Pax.","BRT Pax.","MRT-Board","MRT-Alight","BRT-Board","BRT-Alight"),
                              labels=c("MRT Pax.","BRT Pax.",                                  "MRT-Board","MRT-Alight","BRT-Board","BRT-Alight")) +
            ## Maximum load
            geom_text(mapping=aes(x=Inf,y=Inf,
                      label="Maximum sectional load (1,000 pax/day)",vjust=1.3,hjust=1.02),size=3) +
            geom_text(data=max.mrt,mapping=aes(x=Inf,y=Inf,
                      label=paste0("MRT=",label)), vjust=2.6,hjust=2.4,size=3) +
            geom_text(data=max.brt,mapping=aes(x=Inf,y=Inf,
                      label=paste0("BRT=",label)), vjust=2.6,hjust=1.2,size=3)
        ## Export png
        print(g)
        ## Close printing window
        dev.off()
```

Comment: if you call geom_ribbon before geom_bar the ribbon will be at the back

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I also realized that during trial.

Comment: You can't stack and group at the same time. Reversing the order in `interaction` will change the order. If all else fails, set the levels of the factor manually to the correct order.

Comment: Yes, I also remembered that technique and just updated the post which shows reordered bars by changing its levels. I will give up one remaining issue of *stack and group* at this moment. Thank you.